# How to update file name in filewatcher

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, filenames

Finally, I made coding for automatic updation. The file is added to the database. But i cannot update the file name in the column 0. Its is giving only the first time file name. When i change the file name to something else its not giving in column0.

I just need to enter only the particular file name in the `part`. I dont know how to trim the filename and give in the column0. Please help me out.

**Also, i found an important bug in this.. when ever i use the button to move the file from cell[1] to cell[2]. The entire file is moved to cell[2]. So that time the file watcher is looking to that particular folder and understands,, the file is deleted.. so the code is going to delete the database.. which i don't want to do that.. how can i handle this situation..**

Please help me out

My code snippet for automatic upadation:

```
 namespace shell_FileSystemWatcher
 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public string partKey = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new object of FileSystemWatcher
    /// </summary>
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    ListBox listbox1 = new ListBox();
    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///Creating listbox in current form

        this.Controls.Add(listbox1);
        listbox1.Size = new Size(500, 200);
        listbox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        listbox1.Visible = true;

        ///Assigning some properties to FileSystemWatcher class object
        ///Assign the path 
        watcher.Path = @"C:\user\elec\copy";
        ///Assign the filters as your requirement
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        ///Handle the events that will be called when any file will be changed in the given folder path.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        ///Enabling the event call
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        ///Initializing delegate that we have created to update UI control outside the current thread
        addItemInList = new delAddItem(this.AddString);
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name); 
        switch (e.ChangeType)
        {
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                //Insert file in database
                this.Invoke(addItemInList, "File: " + e.FullPath + " Created");
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Stacy492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO cncinfo (part,draftpath) VALUES ('" + file.Name + "','" + e.FullPath + "') ", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                //remove file from database
                this.Invoke(addItemInList, "File: " + e.FullPath + " Deleted");
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Stacy492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"delete cncinfo where part='" + file.Name + "'  ;", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                ///if you are storing file in database(not file name whole file in binary format)
                ///then you can update the file in database here
                ///this event will be fired when any data has changed in the file.
                this.Invoke(addItemInList, "File: " + e.FullPath + " Changed");
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Stacy492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + NotifyFilters.FileName
                        + "',draftpath='" + e.FullPath + "' where part='" + file.Name + "'", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    this.Validate();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name); 
        //Update then old filename with new here
        this.Invoke(addItemInList, string.Format("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath));

        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Stacy492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            //s.debasish79@gmail.com
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + file.Name
                + "',draftpath='" + e.FullPath + "' where part='" + file.Name + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            this.Validate();
        }


    }

    #region  We are creating delegate to update the value in Windows Form Control
    /// <summary>
    /// We are using delegate invoke method to update the UI control outside the current thread.
    /// otherwise it will throws the error.
    /// you can also use this method to update the cell value in datagridview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_string"></param>
    private delegate void delAddItem(string _string);
    private delAddItem addItemInList;
    private void AddString(string _string)
    {
        listbox1.Items.Add(_string);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: There is no such a event to determine that file has been moved. When you move the file manually to another location then windows initially copy the file into new folder and deletes it from old location.

Comment: @Shell But .. how can i deal this situation.. When i press That button.. i dont want my filewatcher to do the delete action..

Comment: @Shell Also how can i get the filename and update in the column0.. I cannot do that.. Only first time when i create a new document.. i am getting the file name.. rest times.. its not taking... please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the file name this will help you out!!!!

```
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
```